# Bar graph drawing using month from date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

Need to draw a bar chart using below data set. X axis needs to be Territory and Y axis needs to be average production in each territory and hue needs to contain the month from the date column.

[image: data sheet will look like this]

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are asking. When you say average production, do you want to calculate average production from a Territory, or just display the value that is in the production column? If you clarify I can update my answer. In my example I just display the data from the production column. First export your spreadsheet to csv. Then you can do the following:

```py
import calendar
import datetime

import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as ex

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")


def get_month_names(dataframe: pd.DataFrame):
    # Get all the dates
    dates = dataframe["Date"].to_list()
    # Convert date-string to datetime object
    # I assume month/day/year, if it is day/month/year, swap %m and %d
    date_objs = [datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S") for date in dates]
    # Get all the months
    months = [date.month for date in date_objs]
    # Get the names of the months
    month_names = [calendar.month_name[month] for month in months]
    return month_names


fig = ex.bar(x=df["Territory"],
             y=df["Production"],
             color=get_month_names(df))
fig.show()
```

this produces:

[image]